# How to keep the variable value after post back

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to keep the variable value after the post back. I tried it both by session variable and also Viewstate but failed to keep the value of random number same. Every time after button press (after page refresh) I am getting a new random value but I want to keep the same value.

```
//in code behind
public static int RandNumber{ get; set; }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //by using session 
    Session["rand"] = rnd.Next(0, 10);
    RandNumber = Int32.Parse(Session["rand"].ToString());

    //by view state
    int rand = rnd.Next(0, 10);
    ViewState["KEY"] = rand;
    RandNumber = Int32.Parse(ViewState["KEY"].ToString());
}
```

for post back in the form:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

And tried to access in the page as below:

```
<p>Random No: <%= RandNumber %></p>
```

Answer (score 4):

Only set a new random number if it's not a post back by checking IsPostBack

```
    public int RandNumber{ get; set; }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //by using session 
        if(!IsPostBack){
            Session["rand"] = rnd.Next(0, 10);
        }
        RandNumber = Int32.Parse(Session["rand"].ToString());
    }
```